# Why does Regex used by Microsoft EmailAddressAttribute accept value with more than 254 characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I use the [EmailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute to validate if a value provided is a valid email address. A valid value will be stored in a database. I wondered if I should restrict the max size of the email column in the database, and what would be the correct size. I found the [is_email webpage](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/) which states the max length is **254**.

So then I checked the Regex used by the Microsoft EmailAttribute [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs) and used [this online regex checker](https://regexr.com/) to validate a value exceeding 254 characters, and to my surprise it is considered a match?

Is the implementation of the EmailAddress by Microsoft not correct? Or should I combine the EmailAddress attribute with a MaxLength attribute?

Comment: That is not what the RFC says.  It merely stipulates that any conforming implementation should be able to accept an address of up to 254 (?) characters.  And points out that accepting more is quite normal.

Comment: RFC 5321: "There are several objects that have required minimum/maximum sizes. Every implementation MUST be able to receive objects of at least these sizes.  Objects larger than these sizes SHOULD be avoided when possible. [...] To the maximum extent possible, *implementation techniques that impose no limits on the length of these objects should be used*." (emphasis mine). It is reasonable to impose a maximum length if you need one for a legitimate purpose (like a database field), but it's not reasonable for a global test to reject exceeding a particular length.

Comment: Ah, I see the nuance now. Since I am going to store the email address in a database I prefer to use a max length instead of nvarchar(max). Will add a remark in my API documentation that email address is restricted to 254 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `MaxLengthAttribute` to limit the the size of the value.

The `EmailAddressAttribute` validate only how the value is composed either by a Regex or by checking the position of `@` wich should not be the first nor the last character.

.NET Core check only the position of `@` as you can see on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs).

.NET Framework will use the following Regex, or [eventually could check the position of `@` as fallback](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs,29).

```
@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$"
```